# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on string in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php on line 507

Tags: magento-1.9

When trying to delete customer accounts I'm getting a blank white screen this is the full error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on string in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php on line 507

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Does seem like it's loading the customer, so it can't load the ID for the customer.

Custom extension for frontend delete (GDPR) or is this just default admin delete from the grid or delete from inside the customer account view within the admin?

Comment: From the manage customers screen whether i check off a single customer or multiple the same thing happens.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Version of Magento 1?

Comment: version 1.9.3.9

Comment: Are you able to delete directly from the customer page? 

What does your request show in the browser in the network tab when you press submit. Does it show a customer_id?